# error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token

Tags: c

I don't really understand why it doesn't work if somebody can help me

[what i see when compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skaBO.png)

the function hasard_ban return me a structure with the same type as case_b (T_Tab_Case), and I can't fill case_b

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    int nlig, ncol, niveau, next, nban;
    typedef struct T_Tab_Case case_b;
    char **grille;
    int     i, j;


    //On demande les paramètres de la partie au joueur
    parametres(&nlig, &ncol, &niveau, &next, &nban);

    switch(niveau){
        case 1:printf("\nniveau choisi : Débutant\n");break;
        case 2:printf("\nniveau choisi : Intermédiaire\n");break;
        case 3:printf("\nniveau choisi : Difficile\n");break;
        case 4:printf("\nniveau choisi : Expert\n");break;
    };
    //On génère les cases bannies
    case_b = hasard_ban(nban, nlig, ncol);
    i = 0;

    //On alloue la mémoire suffisante pour créer notre tableau
    grille = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (nlig + 2));
    while (i < nlig + 1){
        j = 0;
        grille[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (ncol + 2));
        while (j < ncol + 1)
        {
            grille[i][j] = '-';
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < case_b.n)
    {
        grille[case_b.tab[i].abs][case_b.tab[i].ord] = 'x'; /*les cases bannies sont représentées par des x */
        i++;
    }
    affichage(grille);

    return 0;
}
```

T_Tab_Case is a structure define in header.h

T_Case represents the coordinates

```
typedef struct T_Case{
    int abs;
    int ord;
};

typedef struct T_Tab_Case{
    struct T_Case *tab;
    int n;
};
```

Comment: `case_b` is a type, defined with `typedef`. it is not a variable and you cannot assign to it.

Comment: You need to add inside your switch a "default" rule and remove the ";" after the end } of your switch

Comment: @FlorentSebag good catch with the semicolon, but AFAIK the `default` is entirely optional.

Comment: @FlorentSebag the `;` after the switch simply gets ignored. It's an eye-sore, but surely not a syntax error.

Comment: Gauthier, this is not relevant to your issue and people's opinion on it might differ, but I would suggest to get into the habit of coding in English as early as possible. Once you're out in the industry (or basically as soon as you start collaborating with other people), you will most likely be _required_ to do it.

Comment: @domsson I know but it's still easier to understand when you're french, thanks for that tips

Answer (score 2):

Defining a type-alias with `typedef` has the general syntax

```
typedef type name;  // Define "name" to be an alias of "type"
```

For structures the type is the keyword `struct` followed by the structure tag symbol, for example

```
typedef struct T_Case T_Case;  // Define "T_Case" to be an alias of "struct T_Case"
```

This general syntax is followed also when you combine the `typedef` and structure definition like you want to do:

```
// Define a structure with the tag T_Case,
// and a type-alias of that structure with the same name
typedef struct T_Case{
    int abs;
    int ord;
} T_Case;
```

---

And as mentioned in a comment, when you do

```
typedef struct T_Tab_Case case_b;
```

you define symbol `case_b` that is an alias for `struct T_Tab_Case`. That is , `case_b` is a *type* and not a variable that can be assigned to.

You either want

```
struct T_Tab_Case case_b;  // Define a variable
```

or if you have created an alias for the structure

```
T_Tab_Case case_b;  // Define a variable
```

Comment: Thanks, I should do the same thing for T_Tab_Case i mean ?

Comment: @Gauthier Yes, if you want to make a type-alias for `struct T_Tab_Case`.